# Make an existing code in Java parallel/multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a very simple crawler. I want to make my current code run in a few threads. Could you provide me a little tutorial or article to help me achive this test?

I'm originally a .Net developer and in .Net I have no problem whatsoever running codes in multithread but unfortunately I don't know anything about threads in Java.

My crawler is a command-line software so don't worry about GUI.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of locks ? (I don't know .net)

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Does your code use some sort of queue to maintain all the followup places to crawl?

Comment: @Sword22: Yes. @Dilum: No, since it is a general crawler, it uses a object that implements an interface that has a .next() function which returns a special document for crawler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java does multithreading through the Thread class. One of the most common ways to make existing code multithreaded is to use the Runnable interface to define what you want to call at thread start, and then start it off.

```
public class SomeFunctions
{
  public static void FunctionA() {}
  public static void FunctionB() {}
  public static void FunctionC() {}
}

// ...
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      SomeFunctions.FunctionA();
   }
});
t1.start();

// (rinse and repeat for the other functions)
```

Dry coded, but it should at least get the general concept across. Of course, as soon as you go into multithreading land, you have concurrency issues and need to make sure everything is appropriately syhchronized, etc., but any language will have those issues.

If you're worried about synchronization, you have a few tools at your disposal. The easiest is the recursive mutex functionality built into Java, the "synchronized" keyword. More classical means are also available through various classes in the java.util.concurrent and java.util.concurrent.locks packages such as Semaphore and ReadWriteLock

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html

Comment: +1 @Shirik very nice suggestions and all together the answer. The synchronization is the thing you should focus one and you will certainly have to face.

Comment: Yes, very good answer. Also I found this tutorial that helped me a lot. [Multithreading in Java](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Multithreading-in-Java/)

Answer (score 6):

You can take a look at my webcrawler example. Sry for the lengthiness.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * A web crawler with a Worker pool
 * 
 * @author Adriaan
 */
public class WebCrawler implements Manager {

        private Set<Worker> workers = new HashSet<Worker>();
        private List<String> toCrawl = new ArrayList<String>();
        private Set<String> crawled = new HashSet<String>();
        private Set<String> hosts = new HashSet<String>();
        private Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
        private int maxResults;

        public WebCrawler(String url, int numberOfWorkers, int maxResults) {
                this.maxResults = maxResults;
                toCrawl.add(url);
                createWorkers(numberOfWorkers);
        }

        public void createWorkers(int numberOfWorkers) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++) {
                        workers.add(new Worker(this));
                }
        }

        private void stopWorkers() {
                for (Worker worker : workers) {
                        worker.terminate();
                }
        }

        public synchronized Job getNewJob() {
                while (toCrawl.size() == 0) {
                        try {
                                wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // ignore
                        }
                }
                return new EmailAddressCrawlJob().setDescription(toCrawl.remove(0));
        }

        public synchronized void jobCompleted(Job job) {
                // System.out.println("crawled: " + job.getDescription());
                crawled.add(job.getDescription());
                String host = getHost(job.getDescription());
                boolean knownHost = hosts.contains(host);
                if (!knownHost) {
                        System.out.println("host: " + host);
                        hosts.add(host);
                }
                for (String url : job.getNewDescriptions()) {
                        if (!crawled.contains(url)) {
                                if (knownHost) {
                                        toCrawl.add(toCrawl.size() - 1, url);
                                } else {
                                        toCrawl.add(url);
                                }
                        }
                }
                for (String result : job.getResults()) {
                        if (results.add(result)) {
                                System.out.println("result: " + result);
                        }
                }
                notifyAll();
                if (results.size() >= maxResults) {
                        stopWorkers();
                        System.out.println("Crawled hosts:");
                        for (String crawledHost : hosts) {
                                System.out.println(crawledHost);
                        }
                        Set<String> uncrawledHosts = new HashSet<String>();
                        for (String toCrawlUrl : toCrawl) {
                                uncrawledHosts.add(getHost(toCrawlUrl));
                        }
                        System.out.println("Uncrawled hosts:");
                        for (String unCrawledHost : uncrawledHosts) {
                                System.out.println(unCrawledHost);
                        }
                }
                if (crawled.size() % 10 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("crawled=" + crawled.size() + " toCrawl="
                                        + toCrawl.size() + " results=" + results.size() + " hosts="
                                        + hosts.size() + " lastHost=" + host);
                }
        }

        public String getHost(String host) {
                int hostStart = host.indexOf("://") + 3;
                if (hostStart > 0) {
                        int hostEnd = host.indexOf("/", hostStart);
                        if (hostEnd < 0) {
                                hostEnd = host.length();
                        }
                        host = host.substring(hostStart, hostEnd);
                }
                return host;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
                new WebCrawler("http://www.nu.nl/", 5, 20);
        }
}
```

Worker

```
**
 * A Worker proactively gets a Job, executes it and notifies its manager that
 * the Job is completed.
 * 
 * @author Adriaan
 */
public class Worker extends Thread {

        private final Manager manager;
        private Job job = null;
        private boolean isWorking;

        public Worker(Manager manager) {
                this.manager = manager;
                isWorking = true;
                start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                System.out.println("Worker " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                                + " starting ");
                while (isWorking) {
                        job = manager.getNewJob();
                        job.execute();
                        manager.jobCompleted(job);
                }
        }

        public void terminate() {
                isWorking = false;
        }
}
```

Manager interface

```
/**
 * Manager interface for Workers
 * 
 * @author Adriaan
 */
public interface Manager {

        /**
         * Gets a new job
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public Job getNewJob();

        /**
         * Indicates the job is completed
         * 
         * @param job
         */
        public void jobCompleted(Job job);
}
```

Job

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * A Job is a unit of work defined by a String (the description). During execution the 
 * job can obtain results and new job descriptions.
 *
 * @author Adriaan
 */
public abstract class Job {

        private String description;
        private Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
        private Set<String> newDescriptions = new HashSet<String>();

        /**
         * Sets the job description
         * 
         * @param description
         * @return this for chaining
         */
        public Job setDescription(String description) {
                this.description = description;
                return this;
        }

        /**
         * Executes the job
         */
        public abstract void execute();

        /**
         * Gets the results obtained
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public Set<String> getResults() {
                return results;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the now job descriptions obtained
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public Set<String> getNewDescriptions() {
                return newDescriptions;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the job description
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public String getDescription() {
                return description;
        }

        /**
         * Allows the implementation to add an obtained result
         * 
         * @param result
         */
        void addResult(String result) {
                results.add(result);
        }

        /**
         * Allows the implementation to add an obtained description
         * 
         * @param result
         */
        void addNewDescription(String newDescription) {
                newDescriptions.add(newDescription);
        }
}
```

A Job which crawls a page for email addresses:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * A Job which crawls HTTP or HTTPS URL's for email adresses, collecting new
 * URL's to crawl along the way.
 * 
 * @author Adriaan
 */
public class EmailAddressCrawlJob extends Job {

        @Override
        public void execute() {
                try {
                        URL url = new URL(getDescription());
                        if (url != null) {
                                String text = readText(url);
                                extractNewDescriptions(text, url);
                                extractResults(text);
                        }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        System.err.println("Bad url " + getDescription());
                }
        }

        private String readText(URL url) {
                URLConnection connection;
                try {
                        connection = url.openConnection();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
                        int num = input.read(buffer);
                        if (num > 0) {
                                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, num));
                                while (num != -1) {
                                        num = input.read(buffer);
                                        if (num != -1) {
                                                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, num));
                                        }
                                }
                                return builder.toString();
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        //System.err.println("Could not read from " + url);
                }
                return "";
        }

        private void extractNewDescriptions(String text, URL url) {

                // URL extracting code from Sun example
                String lowerCaseContent = text.toLowerCase();
                int index = 0;
                while ((index = lowerCaseContent.indexOf("<a", index)) != -1) {

                        if ((index = lowerCaseContent.indexOf("href", index)) == -1) {
                                break;
                        }

                        if ((index = lowerCaseContent.indexOf("=", index)) == -1) {
                                break;
                        }

                        index++;
                        String remaining = text.substring(index);
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(remaining, "\t\n\r\">#");
                        String strLink = st.nextToken();

                        if (strLink.startsWith("javascript:")) {
                                continue;
                        }

                        URL urlLink;
                        try {
                                urlLink = new URL(url, strLink);
                                strLink = urlLink.toString();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                // System.err.println("Could not create url: " + target
                                // + " + " + strLink);
                                continue;
                        }
                        // only look at http links
                        String protocol = urlLink.getProtocol();
                        if (protocol.compareTo("http") != 0
                                        && protocol.compareTo("https") != 0) {
                                // System.err.println("Ignoring: " + protocol
                                // + " protocol in " + urlLink);
                                continue;
                        }
                        addNewDescription(urlLink.toString());
                }
        }

        private void extractResults(String text) {
                Pattern p = Pattern
                                .compile("([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
                while (m.find()) {
                        addResult(m.group(1));
                }
        }
}
```

I know this answer is a bit verbose, but I thought OP might be best helped with a working example and I happened to have made one not so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic java program that will give the abstract idea of the Multi Threading..

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

  String word;

  public MyThread(String rm){
    word = rm;
  }

  public void run(){

    try {

      for(;;){
        System.out.println(word);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }

    } catch(InterruptedException e) {

      System.out.println("sleep interrupted");      
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t1=new MyThread("First Thread");
    Thread t2=new MyThread("Second Thread");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

**And the Output will be..**

```
First Thread
Second Thread
First Thread
Second Thread
First Thread
```

Go with this PPT it will help you with the basics..

[Here](http://www.utdallas.edu/~veerasam/AdvJava/Multithreading.ppt)

Comment: I wouldn't make endless for loops. Maybe add a counter so that you can run the loop 10 times? (10 is just an example).

Answer (score 0):

**Use Runnable instead of extending Thread:**

Instead of extending the Thread class, it is better to implement the Runnable interface, which separates the task of running a thread from the thread itself. By implementing the Runnable interface, the run() method will be invoked on the object passed to the constructor, and we can use a single Thread object to execute multiple Runnable objects.

**Use a constant for the sleep time:**

Instead of hard-coding the sleep time (1000 milliseconds), use a constant to make it more readable and easy to change. For example, you could declare a private static final int SLEEP_TIME = 1000; at the beginning of the class and use it in the sleep() call.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private String word;

    public MyRunnable(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(word);
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("sleep interrupted");
        }
    }

    private static final int SLEEP_TIME = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable("First Thread"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable("Second Thread"));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```