# Writing a web crawler in Java

Tags: java, web-crawler, web-scraping

How do I write a page scraper in Java to crawl the web and obtain information related to a particular topic.On searching Google I found only 1 video on youttube with  no subsequent parts and a book by Jeff Heaton.If anyone has any good links or knows where to start to make Java page scraper can you please post it.

Comment: "bot" is a bad term. What you should be searching for is a "page crawler" or "page scraper".

Comment: okay.Sorry.Have chnaged it now

Comment: I wrote a multi-threaded webcrawler a while back, without using any libraries. Maybe it's a good starting point for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005137/make-an-existing-code-in-java-parallel-multithread/6007022#6007022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library for this. The [JSoup CookBook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) is a good start.