# How write mulithreaded code and accumulate the output from all the threads in a single file

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This question is somewhat similar to [Make an existing code in Java parallel/multithread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005137/make-an-existing-code-in-java-parallel-multithread)

I didn't find answer specific to my question, so I am posting below.

I am trying to make an existing application multithreaded to decrease execution time.

Here is my (for brevity) simplified version existing application code

```
for(MyClass myObject : myObjectSet) {              
    String outputString=myLongRunningMethod(myObject);   
    fileWriter.append(outputString+"\n");
}

fileWriter.close();
```

Here I attempted to make it multi-threaded.Becuase `myLongRunningMethod` is the slowest piece.

```
ExecutorService threadExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(myObjectSet.size());
```

// Semaphore implementation
    ResourcePool resourcePool = new ResourcePool(myObjectSet.size());

```
for(MyClass myObject:myObjectSet) {             
       Object key = resourcePool.getItem();      

       MyClassMT myClassMT = new MyClassMT(myObject);
       threadExec.execute(myClassMT);                      
 }
```

Where MyClassMT is:

```
public class MyClassMT implements Runnable{

    MyClass myObject;

    public MyClassMT(MyClass myObject) {
        this.myObject=myObject
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       String outString= myLongRunningMethod(this.myObject);
       System.out.println(outString);   
    }
}
```

**Problem/Question**

My attempted multi-threaded code seems to be running fine, because I can see an expected output in the console but I no more safely able to write the output of `myLongRunningMethod` to file using `fileWriter`. Also, I can see in profiler that all the threads are still alive even after they have done processing `myObject`

How to write output in a file after all the elements in myObjectSet is processed. i.e. to get back my original functionality in multi-threaded way. And then stop all the threads.

Is there any easier/better implementation? Maybe the one which involves guava [Futures](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html)
Am I really required to use MyResource which is similar to code here [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

BTW, I tried setting `outString` as field of `MyClassMT`  and tried getting it back in the code after  just after`threadExec.execute(myClassMT);` , that didn't work.

Not shown in code, a new fileWriter will be created for every myObjectSet.

Please let me know if need more information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to write output in a file after all the elements in myObjectSet is processed. i.e. to get back my original functionality in multi-threaded way.

Using the `Future<String>` is the right way of doing this.  You need to turn `MyClassMT` into a `Callable<String>` and use `threadExec.submit(myCallable)`.  This returns a `Future<String>` which, after you have submitted all of your tasks can be used to get the results of each of the thread's work.

```
public class MyClassMT implements Callable<String> {
    ...
    public String call() {
       ...
    }
```

You can also use `threadExec.invokeAll(...)` to invoke all of your `Callable<String>` classes.  This returns a `List<Future<String>>`.

Then you can do something like:

```
List<Future<String>> futures = threadExec.invokeAll(myClassMTCollection);
// always shutdown the pool once you are done submitting
threadExec.shutdown();
for (Future<String> future : futures) {
    // this can throw an exception that the thread threw
    String result = future.get();
}
```

> And then stop all the threads.

After you have submitted all of the tasks, you need to call `shutdown()` on the pool.  The submitted jobs continue to run but once the jobs are done the threads will be shutdown.  If you don't do this your application will never finish.

> ExecutorService threadExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(myObjectSet.size());

If you are doing something like this then you really should be using the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` which will fork a new thread whenever needed.  Really, if your threads are CPU intensive, you should pick some number around he number of cores with the fixed thread pool and *not* allocate a new thread for *every* task.

Comment: `Really, if your threads are CPU intensive, you should pick some number around he number of cores with the fixed thread pool and not allocate a new thread for every task.` I totally agree with you on this. I have set it as 8 in my real code.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show usage of `invokeAll(...)` @Watt.

Comment: Additional question, as I mentioned, my application originally is not multithreaded. I am making just this small piece of code inside my big app multithreaded. Will this change in any way make my application thread un safe, so that our customers won't able to anymore run entire application in a multi-threaded way. i.e. Will this still work if the entire application itself is running in multi-threaded way.

Comment: Don't think so unless your `myLongRunningMethod(...)` does something unsafe.  Just adding more threads doesn't change the safety of any application.  The question is what are those threads doing?  If they are accessing or modifying global state then you need to synchronize around those operations @Watt.

Comment: @Watt you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` when you create your fixed thread-pool.

Comment: @Watt does the order of the output strings matter?  If not, this should work great.  If so, you may have to associate an int with the result, sort, then output.

Comment: That's not true @user949300.  The order of the `invokeAll(...)` result `List` is defined in being in the same order as the submitted callables.

Comment: Thanks, I have learned something.  I know they don't necessarily execute / finish in order, and I assumed the return was in that semi-random order.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is just another variation of standard (multiple) producer(s)-consumer problem in multi-threading. There are many different solutions for this kind of problem, I would favour message queue approach in this case - but this is just my personal preference.