# how to calculate pixel count of three images at same time

Tags: java

How can i calculate total pixel of three images at the same time?
I was tried with java Swing Worker and Thread, i got the answer but it takes 1.30 min to return total pixel count(30 seconds for each image, image size 480*303) of specified range. But I need to get answers of three images at same time within 30 sec.

```
public class ImageProcessor1 implements Runnable{
static int blackPix=0;
BufferedImage tempImg;
public static int blackPixel=0;
public ImageProcessor1(String path) throws Exception{
tempImg = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
}

private static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
    int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);

    int rgb[] = new int[]{
        (argb >> 16) & 0xff, //red
        (argb >> 8) & 0xff, //green
        (argb) & 0xff //blue
    };
    System.out.println("Process1 :rgb: " + rgb[0] + " " + rgb[1] + " " + rgb[2]);
    return rgb;
}

@Override
public void run() {
     int[][] pixelData = new int[tempImg.getHeight() * tempImg.getWidth()][3];
        int[] rgb;
        int height=tempImg.getHeight();
        int width=tempImg.getWidth();
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                rgb = getPixelData(tempImg, i, j);
                if(rgb[0]<125 && rgb[0]>105 && rgb[1]<125 && rgb[1]>105 && rgb[2]<125 && rgb[2]>105)
                {
                    blackPixel+=1;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Show us some code? Why does it even take 30 secs to return total pixel count for 1 image?

Comment: Your question is misleading. It sounds as though you would want to count the total number of all pixels of three images. But judging from your code it looks like you are trying to count the number of a specific pixel value range in all three images.

Comment: sir i am actually trying to count the pixels of the given range. its working but i want to know how it is possible to get total count at same time. it is a part of real time process so i need to compare three counts and i need minimum of three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very strange that iterating over such a small picture takes you 30 seconds!

After a little profiling it seems, that having a println-statement in a hot loop is slowing you down dramatically.

After little modification of your code , a 10500x5788 image takes ~3secs on my machine.

The modified version:

```
package application;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageProcessor1 implements Runnable {

  BufferedImage tempImg;
  public static int blackPixel = 0;

  public ImageProcessor1(final String path) throws Exception {
    final long start = System.nanoTime();

    tempImg = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    // Use tracing, profiling and sampling to proof performance issues and fixes
    System.out.println("ImageIO took " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start)
        + " ms.");
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    final int height = tempImg.getHeight();
    System.out.println("Getting height '" + height + "' took "
        + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start) + " ms.");


    start = System.nanoTime();
    final int width = tempImg.getWidth();
    System.out.println("Getting width '" + width + "' took "
        + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start) + " ms.");

    start = System.nanoTime();

    // reuse variables
    int argb;
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        // HOT LOOP. Do as little as possible. No println calls!
        argb = tempImg.getRGB(i, j);

        // inline all method calls
        red = argb >> 16 & 0xff; // red
        green = argb >> 8 & 0xff; // green
        blue = argb & 0xff; // blue

        if (red < 125 && red > 105 && green < 125 && green > 105 && blue < 125 && blue > 105) {
          blackPixel += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Iterating pixels took "
        + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start) + " ms.");
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ImageProcessor1("big.jpg").run();
    System.out.println("Number of blackpixels = " + blackPixel);
  }

}
```

On a more general note, you have to be careful with your approach, because you read all of the image into RAM, and then process it. If you do that with 3 or more large images at once, there is a chance of an OutOfMemoryError. If that becomes an issue, you could read an image in as an input stream and process only small buffers of the image at a time.

To see how this can be done see http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/source/ij/io/ImageReader.java .

To see how to accumulate the output of multiple threads , see [How write mulithreaded code and accumulate the output from all the threads in a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188997/how-write-mulithreaded-code-and-accumulate-the-output-from-all-the-threads-in-a) .